# Rails, how to limit a nested resource count?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Given something like:

```
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :item_options, :limit => 10, :reject_if => lambda { |a| a[:title].blank? }, :allow_destroy => true
```

class ItemOption < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :item

How can I make it so an ItemOption can not be added if there are already 10 or more Item Options for an Item?

The accepts_nested_attributes_for seems to only work when creating an item and not take effect when you later try to add ItemOptions.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The rails api say that about the :limit option :

"Allows you to specify the maximum number of the associated records that can be processed with the nested attributes. If the size of the nested attributes array exceeds the specified limit, NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords exception is raised. If omitted, any number associations can be processed. Note that the :limit option is only applicable to one-to-many associations."

If you want exactly the behaviour of the :limit option, you can write a function like that in your model :

```
def item_options_attributes= items_options_hash
  raise NestedAttributes::TooManyRecords if item_options.size + items_options_hash.size > 10
  super
end
```

Answer (score -1):

accepts_nested_attributes_for does only work when creating an item. I'm assuming when you creating an item you have a nested form that also accepts ItemOptions?

To deal with the case where you want to add ItemOptions I think you should use a before filter.

Something like this in the ItemOption model that counts how many there are and returns false (which will cancel the create).

```
before_create :check_option_count

def check_option_count
  if self.item.options.count > 10 return false
end
```